# Program that is dependent on command line arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a program, which generally takes 2 command line inputs. But my program has to check explicitly if command line arguments are given or not. I tried

```
sys.argv[1] == NULL and sys.argv[2] == NULL
```

but this statement is invalid. How do we check for empty command line arguments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as `NULL` in Python. Python calls it `None`. Also, if you attempt to index into a list beyond the list's end you will get an exception, so check how long it is.

Comment: So, why did you believe that NULL was a valid construct in Python? How are you learning Python? If it's from a book, please carefully read the first two or three chapters which introduce the basics.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv` is a list of the arguments, so you want to check to see if the length is equal to one (`sys.argv[0]` will always be the name of the script):

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    # no arguments provided
```